# create table with auto_increment that starts at 10 and increments by 10

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an auto_increment field for a table I'm creating but I am not getting the desired results.

**create statement**

```
create table if not exists departments(
    department_id integer primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    department_name varchar(50) not null,
    manager_id int(20) not null,
    location_id int(20) not null    
)AUTO_INCREMENT = 10 engine=innodb;
```

**current output after insertion**

```
+---------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| department_id | department_name | manager_id | location_id |
+---------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
|            10 | Administration  |        200 |        1700 |
|            11 | Administration  |        200 |        1700 |
+---------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
```

**desired output after insertion**

```
+---------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
| department_id | department_name | manager_id | location_id |
+---------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
|            10 | Administration  |        200 |        1700 |
|            20 | Administration  |        200 |        1700 |
+---------------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
```

I only want to set this auto_increment for the one table `departments`.

Comment: i think [`auto_increment_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) increment step is specific to certain engines ( not innodb )

Comment: The table already has an auto_increment of 10 if you look at the last line of the create

Comment: That auto increment is just the start value, you can't set the offset for a single table.Do you need that output in your database or in your reports? Otherwise you could just do SELECT (department_id) * 10) as department_id

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but Mysql just does just not support it.

I have to ask the question why do you want to do it in the first place?  Auto increment IDs are usually opaque and the only thing you care about is that they are unique.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL increment will only go from 1 to 1. If you want it going 10 to 10 and depending on what's the purpose of it, you have two main options :

1. Have a unique int column that you populate from your application logic (not auto incremented, incrementation will be handled in the application) :
   department_id integer primary key
2. Have the normal auto increment column and multiply it by 10 before you use it in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this straight up because the auto increment offset (the number it will be increased by) can't be set for each table separately, a workaround would be :

```
 INSERT INTO myDepartments(department_id,department_name,manager_id,location_id)
    SELECT (department_id * 10) as department_id,
     department_name , manager_id , location_id 
    FROM departments
```

Create a new table that has the exact same fields, write a trigger that will add values to your new table as they are inserted in your old table, all logic that has already been written will still work with the old table and all new logic that works with the *10 system will also work if you use the new table (make sure not to do inserts in your new table), downside: you will have 2 tables with the same data except for the id

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer here is that MySQL doesn't support auto increment offsets **per table**, it does support it globally per database. You asked how to do this per table - it won't work.

The other problem is that you *might* be tempted to "manually" calculate this value. Just don't. If you require auto_increment for some beautifying purposes - don't use it. Its only job is to give unique numbers, and offsetting is used for replication purposes.

I suggest creating another column which you update from within a single process or use MySQL event scheduler to periodically update records with a number.